# JS - Waiting for a function to finish

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I have the following code from my test that is causing me some issues:

```
var array = []
for (var b = 0; b < ToAdd.length; b++) {
        page.open(itemsToAdd[b])
        page.load()
        array.push(page.titleElement)
        page.addToCartButton.click()
}
```

What I expect is, `array.push(page.titleElement)` to complete its execution before `page.addToCartButton.click()`.

How do i achieve this is JS?

Regards.

Comment: What is happening currently?

Comment: On the second iteration - it complains it cannot find the `page.titleElement`. If i comment that code out its all fine. Likewise, if I comment the `page.addToCartButton.click()` and leave `page.titleElement` it works. I just can;t have them in at the same time

Comment: You have answered your own, BTW answer is given by mate.

Comment: @Amogh sorry didnt understand

Answer (score 1):

Put the page.addToCartButton.click() outside the for loo if you're waiting for all the pushes to be done. Otherwise the code should be just fine.

Comment: But i need all the items in the array `itemsToAdd[b]` to be added - so if I take the click addtoCart out how will it actually add them

Comment: I suppose `ToAdd.length` in for condition is total items to add, so as suggested if you take out click event then for will add items.

Comment: @Amogh - thanks but sorry - still dont understand how that would look - if I take out the click action, but my repeated actions steps are : Go To Page -> Get Title -> Click add cart

Comment: Okay, so you are saying for each element in itemToAdd you want to execute click action, am I right now? And what is "page" in this context? I guess its document

Answer (score 0):

webdriver.io is a framework that only if you can see the component, you can choose it to click or do some actions, if not, you can't do the actions about that component.

What's more, the framework may not find it before the DOMS are rendered.
So you may use the `browser.pause(3000)` to wait for the component to render. You can also make the next actions wait a moment to solve the problem, I hope this will help you.